# Symfony php.ini Debian

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, debian

I'm using Debian 7 amd64 LAMP server on Oracle VM VirtualBox.
I'm trying to install Symfony and I'm having some lil problems

When I run command:
**php my_project_name/app/check.php**

It says:

**[ERROR]**
Your system is not ready to run Symfony2 projects.
Fix the following mandatory requirements:

- date.timezone setting must be set > Set the "date.timezone" setting in php.ini* (like Europe/Paris).

I have already tried to edit php.ini file with following command:
**sudo nano/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

and there under **[date]** section; deleted **;** and edited to: **date.timezone = Europe/Helsinki**

after that restarted.

in http://localhost/phpinfo.php there is correct Timezone.

Default timezone Europe/Helsinki,
(Local Value)
date.timezone Europe/Helsinki,
(Master Value)
 Europe/Helsinki

Any tips? May there be another php.ini file Symfony uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the check script via command line, so the php.ini is different between the CLI and apache.
For find the correct php.ini for the cli lauch the following command:

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

And check the `Loaded Configuration File` line

Hope this help