# Fake $_SERVER variables in phpUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm still new to phpUnit and I can't make my (very simple) test work.

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class userTest extends TestCase {
    public function testTrue() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);

        //  This line wont work without autloader.php
        $user = new User();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I need to load all my classes from autoloader.php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit bootstrap="inc/autoload.php"></phpunit>
```

But I'n those classes I have a lot of $SERVER variables, like

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['HTTPS']
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

This is the error I get:

```
Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sakkadentrainer/classes/App.php on line 674
```

How can I make those variables work? I would prefer to kind of "fake" them as env.variables from the phpunit.xml file, but I don't know if that's possible.

Thanks for you help!

My Setup:
    php 7.1.2, phpUnit 6.1.1, macOs Mojave, MAMP

**SOLUTION**:
https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables

Comment: These are all valid variables: https://secure.php.net/reserved.variables.server

Comment: Try settings the variable as described [here in the doc](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables)

Comment: Hey Matteo: I was look for that! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to the Doc, you can [Setting PHP INI settings, Constants and Global Variables](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables), as example:

```
<php>
  <server name="REMOTE_ADDR" value="127.0.0.1"/>
</php>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: Something else: I now get this error: Error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found. Its due to an unloaded php extension (php_intl.dll). I tried to add it in phpunit.xml: <ini name="extension" value="ext/php_intl.dll" /> But it does not work...

Comment: Probably you should add it in the php.ini

Comment: which php.ini? the one from MAMP or does phpUnit has an own php.ini?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30047099/2270041 in order to find the correct files to edit

Comment: Thanks, but I can't locate my php.ini. `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` return /etc. But in /etc I only have a php.ini.default file. From phpUnit and its phpinfo I know that `post_max_size` is 8MB. So i tried to find the php.ini file with this value. I found one in `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` but the changes in this file, didn't affect phpunti... I'm lost ;)

Comment: What a pain... I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516071/2839368. I needed to copy the php.ini.default file to etc/ and rename it as php.ini